# Pytorch tensor.shape[3] get a tensor?

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

[image: tensor.shape]

As my picture, I have a tensor: `X`, and when I use `SummaryWriter` to `add_graph(net, X)`, `X.shape[3]` becomes a `tensor`. Why? It always was an int.

ENV: torch==1.10.2+cu113 , Ubuntu20.04, Python3.8.10

Comment: you can use X.size(dim=3) instead?

Comment: I have tried that, same to shape[3]

Comment: Which PyTorch version are you using?

Comment: torch==1.10.2+cu113 , Ubuntu20.04,Python3.8.10.Sorry, I should describe env before.